# Difference between 友情【ゆうじょう】 and 友好【ゆうこう】

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Is there a difference between [友情]{ゆうじょう} and [友好]{ゆうこう}?

They both mean friendship in the dictionary. My guess is that 友好 is used to describe more a friendship between countries or organizations. In other words, 友好, or more like allies or a business agreement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

友情 is mainly used for friendship between persons like 彼との友情は、永遠だ(My friendship with him is eternal).

友好 means "goodwill, amity, friendship". For example, 彼の態度は友好的だ(He has a friendly attitude), 日本は、アメリカとは友好的な関係だ(Japan has a friendly relationship with the U.S.).

I think 友情 is a deeper and more personal friendship than 友好.

Comment: 分かった。ありがとうございます。